# How do I use polygons as hair in blender

Tags: particles, physics, geometry

I am trying to make a Vocaloid in blender 2.74 and want to know if anyone could tell me how to make the hair particle system in to a object hair while being able to get a realistic and smooth motion when the hair moves. Like the one in the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FknMQ0mXECE I think they have used a different program. I want to use blender to make this as I would also like to learn how to rig the body better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not much into animation, but by the look of it in the linked video I would say it has more in common with the behavior of fabric than with hair.

You could probably achieve that with a cloth simulation instead of a hair particle system, that way you can model your hair mesh the way you want and have it behave physically as if it were soft.

Comment: How would I do that is there a tutorial on it. I am a total noob in blender well I am getting better.

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHWflWRkYo0